# Rails engine doesn't eagerly load app files while seeding db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load, rails-engines, seed

I'm trying to add install task to my mountable engine `units`.

The task loads seed, and inside it clears some table:

```
# lib/tasks/units_tasks.rake
namespace :units
  task :install do
    Units::Engine.load_seed
  end
end

# db/seeds.rb
Units::Item.delete_all
...
```

When I call the task from a command line

```
$ bundle exec rake units:install
# => NameError: uninitialized constant Units::Item
```

The engine is required as usual (and the gem itself works fine with all its
dependencies except for the case above).

```
# lib/units.rb
require 'units/engine'
module Units
end

# lib/units/engine.rb
module Units
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Units
  end
end
```

Obviously it is loaded without files, that should be eagerly loaded. But why?

Answer (score 1):

In your seed method, you will need

```
require_relative '../lib/units'
```

or potentially

```
require_relative '../lib/units/engine'
```

Then you should be able to namespace as you have been previously.

I believe this has something to do with the threadsafe nature of rails, but a more technical reason is beyond me.